# Does file_get_contents() increase bandwidth usage?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, bandwidth

I am using a file to store some basic data. The file like `script.php` which uses `file_get_contents()` to get data from let's say `data.dat` are on same server. Does it still result in bandwidth usage?

I access the file like this

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('data.dat');
```

Comment: Only if you're accessing the file with a public link. Otherwise, you won't use any outgoing traffic.

Comment: @DaveChen I have included the line I use to access the file. From your comment it appears that I am not using any bandwidth. Is it correct?

Comment: You're not going to use any traffic with that specific line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `file_get_contents()` to bring a file on the server into a string object will not use any bandwidth since it's all local to the server. If you decide to put that content into the resulting `html` response, then it will affect the bandwidth, but that's up to your program.

Comment: This function can also result in incoming bandwidth too, by referring to HTTP URLs.

Comment: Yes, but OP says "get data from let's say data.dat are on same server."

Comment: Oh yes, I agree: I was just giving another example of when this function _would_ incur bandwidth `:-)`.